# React Native app crashes

Tags: react-native

The app has page called Home, and this is the code for home. When the app runs, it
crashes. Please find the possible error and try to fix the problem on this source code.
Note: We assume that the API response is 200 and nothing wrong with the data.

```
import React, { Component, } from ‘react’ ;
import { View, Text } from ‘react-native’ ;
import PropTypes from 'prop-types' ;
import Api from ‘../../utils/api’ ;
import * as styles from ‘../../styles/styles’ ;

class HomeView extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this .state = { data: null };
    }

    render () {
        Api. fetchData ( this .props.name, this .props.phoneNumber)
            . then (response => {
                self .setState({data: response.data});
                self.props.onUpdate({ data: response.data});
        });
        return (
            < View style={style.container}>
                < Text style={style.row}>
                    {this.state.data.fullName}
                </ Text >
                < Text style={style.row}>
                    {this.state.data.phoneNumber}
                </ Text >
                < Text style={style.row}>
                    {this.state.data.maritalStatus}
                </ Text >
            </ View >
        )
    }
}

const style = styles.homeView;
HomeView. propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes .string,
    phoneNumber: PropTypes .string,
}
HomeView. defaultProps = {
    name: 'Aliens',
    phoneNumber: '+999999999',
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove space in `Api. fetchData`

```
Api.fetchData ( this.props.name, this.props.phoneNumber)
  .then (response => {
  self.setState({data: response.data});
  self.props.onUpdate({ data: response.data});
});
```